# Is there a way to pull specific YouTube or TikTok videos into my app?

Tags: youtube, tiktok

I've built an app for skiers. The first version of it is in the app stores now. I'd like to add another feature, but I'm not sure it's possible. Hopefully someone here will know.

A favourite pastime of skiers before they go on holiday is finding out what the skiing conditions are like at the resort they are about to visit. Luckily people in the resorts regularly make videos describing the conditions (colloquially known as 'snow reports') and upload them to YouTube and TikTok.

My app has sections for hundreds of ski resorts around the world. Accordingly what I'd like to do is automatically search for and pull these 'snow report' videos and put them in my app, sorted by date posted and the resort they pertain to.

An example might make things clearer. Here is a 'snow report' video for the ski resort of Sauze d'Oulx, posted on 3rd Feb 2023: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oT2q-Eu_uNU

I'd like to pull this video into the Sauze d'Oulx section of my app, either by utilising words in the title, or by hashtags if the creator attaches any (in this case the relevant hashtags would be #snowreport and #sauzedoulx).

Can this kind of thing be done?

I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Do some research, and try some things yourself. If all else fails, [edit] your question to include everything you tried, including a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Concerning searching videos based on:

- their title, you can use [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint thanks to [`q`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#q) filter and [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint with [`part=snippet`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#part).
- their hashtags, I recommend you to try out my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/6acfae46cc74819b29dd3b70bd8b4764c2bd807e/search.php#L92-L105) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by fetching https://yt.lemnoslife.com/search?part=snippet&hashtag=YOUR_HASHTAG, you will get the videos you are looking for in `items`.

With the hashtag [`snowreport`](https://www.youtube.com/hashtag/snowreport) you would get:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "nextPageToken": "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",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": {
                "kind": "youtube#video",
                "videoId": "R_a5nsD8TQo"
            },
            "snippet": {
                "channelId": "UCPIHD_lP7798nXNM8YQSk9Q",
                "title": "M\u00e9ribel Snow Report (11 January 2023)",
                "thumbnails": [
                    {
                        "url": "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/R_a5nsD8TQo\/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEiCKgBEF5IWvKriqkDFQgBFQAAAAAYASUAAMhCPQCAokN4AQ==&rs=AOn4CLCbHAQMkFAhGqGsnSELZvsOZVoKwA",
                        "width": 168,
                        "height": 94
                    },
                    ...
                ],
                "channelTitle": "Skipedia",
                "channelHandle": null,
                "timestamp": "4 weeks ago",
                "duration": 137,
                "views": 1025,
                "badges": [],
                "channelApproval": null,
                "channelThumbnails": [
                    {
                        "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/ytc\/AL5GRJXLZ5UkDlL2HztSvmhRCb-z3Q47dnga4efZQ_BV=s68-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
                        "width": 68,
                        "height": 68
                    }
                ],
                "detailedMetadataSnippet": null,
                "chapters": []
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Note that my API supports [the pagination mechanism à la YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination).