# Is there a way to create a list of links to YouTube videos with specific hastags in Python?

Tags: python, youtube, scrape

So for example I want to make a data frame of YouTube videos with #stackoverflow in them.
How do I achieve this using python?
Are there any limits to it?
Kinda lost on how to start on this.

Comment: If you don't know how to start this project, try something simpler first. Start with scraping anything from a simpler website and build up to what you actually want to do. There are many tutorials to help you, like this one: [https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python](https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/)

Comment: Maybe [my Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75403210) will partially interest you.